# PHP dynamic query building to support positive and negative like match queries when null

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database table that is in the following format that holds a version of car makes and models:

**Car make, model table**

```
| car_id | make | model |
-------------------------
| 1      | audi | a1    |
| 2      | audi | a2    |
```

**Car version table**

```
| car_version_id | car_id | version   |
---------------------------------------
| 1              | 1      | NULL      |
| 2              | 1      | business  |
| 3              | 2      | NULL      |
| 4              | 2      | business  |
| 5              | 2      | sport     |
```

**Lookup item table - separate uncontrolled data provided by third party api - this is a sample, more like tens of thousands**

```
| item_id | make | model | title                                      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1       | audi | a1    | audi a1 es edition                         |
| 2       | audi | a1    | audi a1 business edition                   |
| 3       | audi | a2    | audi a2 sport edition 45k miles            |
| 4       | audi | a2    | audi a2 37k miles 2.0 liter                |
| 5       | audi | a1    | audi a1 clean inside, 34k miles, 1.0 liter |
```

I loop through each of the car models, get the versions for each and then use the data to search in a listing database of cars - both separate.

At the moment it would perform the following pseudo style queries:

```
1. SELECT * FROM item WHERE make = audi AND model = 'a1'
2. SELECT * FROM item WHERE make = audi AND model = 'a1' AND title LIKE '%business%'
3. SELECT * FROM item WHERE make = audi AND model = 'a1'
4. SELECT * FROM item WHERE make = audi AND model = 'a1' AND title LIKE '%business%'
5. SELECT * FROM item WHERE make = audi AND model = 'a1' AND title LIKE '%sport%'
```

**The Problem**

The problem here is that the business and sport models will appear in the search queries where there is no "title LIKE" because the value is NULL.

What I want to achieve is the following:

```
1. SELECT * FROM item WHERE make = audi AND model = 'a1' AND title NOT LIKE '%business%'
2. SELECT * FROM item WHERE make = audi AND model = 'a1' AND title LIKE '%business%'
3. SELECT * FROM item WHERE make = audi AND model = 'a1' AND title NOT LIKE '%business%' AND title NOT LIKE '%sport%'
4. SELECT * FROM item WHERE make = audi AND model = 'a1' AND title LIKE '%business%' AND title NOT LIKE '%sport%'
5. SELECT * FROM item WHERE make = audi AND model = 'a1' AND title LIKE '%sport%' AND title NOT LIKE '%business%'
```

Another issue is that the combinations of make, model and version values are dynamic so you could have an instance of one make, model and then 10 versions of the car, resulting in long queries.

**Code so far**

I am using php with Symfony for this project.

So far I loop through the cars, get the versions and do the above queries:

```
<?php

$cars  = $this->getCars();

foreach ($cars as $car) {

    $make = $car->version;
    $model = $car->model;
    $versions = $car->versions;

    foreach ($versions as $version) {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE make = '$make' AND model = '$model'";

        if (!is_null($version)) {
            $query .= " AND title LIKE '%$version%'";
        }

        // do query lookup here
    }
}
```

**Question**

So the question is, how can I expand on the current php solution to incorporate what I need it to do with the negative matching combined with the positive matching?

Comment: Why not use `AND version  IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: @dekel question updated, this is due to the second database style and version not being specified - it's a string of data which the version is either in or not in - (string|NULL) so it needs negative lookups.

Comment: why dont you use right inner join so you get only the matching values without null values? and by the way there is not car field in your tables...What i suggest is this SELECT * FROM car_version_table cvt INNER JOIN ON car_make_model_table cmmt WHERE make = '$make' AND model = '$model' AND ((title LIKE %business%) OR (title LIKE %sports%)).

Comment: @helldawg13 not sure the right join does anything differently apart from put it into one query, still have the same issue

Comment: Can you show what the expected output would be if the car is the audi a1? Also, it seems like you want to run each of those individual selects to get 1 record from `item` at a time. Or no?

Comment: So, when the version is null, you want to only match `item`s that don't have any of the "not null" versions in the title?

Comment: @Terminus yes exactly

Comment: It would be easier to simply fetch all items for a given make and model combination from your 3rd party API (no additional where clauses), and categorize the results in php. Is this an acceptable approach for your use case?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possible to get what you want with one (admittedly, kinda gross) query. Instead of iterating over the versions, just use versions in the database by joining on the relevant tables.

Regardless of whether you want to use the versions from $car->versions or not, the answer is using the sub-query in the join condition to only find titles that don't contain any not null versions.

```
SELECT ver.version, i.title
FROM car c
INNER JOIN car_version ver ON c.car_id = ver.car_id
INNER JOIN item i ON
    c.make = i.make AND
    c.model = i.model AND (
        ver.version IS NOT NULL AND
        i.title LIKE CONCAT('%', ver.version, '%' OR
        ver.version IS NULL AND
        (
            SELECT COUNT (1)
            FROM car_version ver2
            WHERE ver2.car_id = c.car_id AND
            ver2.version IS NOT NULL AND
            i.title LIKE CONCAT('%', ver2.version, '%'
        ) = 0
    )
WHERE c.make=? AND c.model=?
```

Question marks are there to suggest the use of parameterized queries. There are some car models that contain `'` that would inadvertently cause sql-injection. Only mention it because I can't tell if you're already handling that.

Let's say you do want to use `$car->versions`. You can add the versions to the `WHERE` clause.

```
$query = "... WHERE c.make=? AND c.model=? AND ver.version IN ('" . implode("','", $car->versions) . "';";
```

And that would still let you run the just one query to get all results. (Using implode is optimistic that there won't be any `'` in the versions. You might have to dynamically prepare the query.)